# How do I Access File Properties on Windows Vista with Python?

Tags: python, winapi, windows-vista, properties

The question is as simple as in the title, how do I access windows file properties like date-modifed, and more specifically tags, with Python? For a program I'm doing, I need to get lists of all the tags on various files in a particular folder, and I'm not sure on how to do this. I have the win32 module, but I don't see what I need.

Thanks guys, for the quick responses, however, the main stat I need from the files is the tags attribute now included in windows vista, and unfortunately, that isn't included in the os.stat and stat modules. Thank you though, as I did need this data, too, but it was more of an after-thought on my part.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [os.stat](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.stat) with [stat](http://docs.python.org/library/stat.html)

```
import os
import stat
import time

def get_info(file_name):
    time_format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"
    file_stats = os.stat(file_name)
    modification_time = time.strftime(time_format,time.localtime(file_stats[stat.ST_MTIME]))
    access_time = time.strftime(time_format,time.localtime(file_stats[stat.ST_ATIME]))
    return modification_time, access_time
```

You can get lots of other stats, check the stat module for the full list.
To extract info for all files in a folder, use [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk)

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(/path/to/your/folder):
    for name in files:
        print get_info(os.path.join(root, name))
```

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, you need to use the [Windows Search API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb331575(VS.85).aspx) looking for [System.Keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787519(VS.85).aspx) -- you can access the API directly via [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html), or indirectly (needing [win32 extensions](http://python.net/crew/skippy/win32/Downloads.html)) through the API's [COM Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb286799(VS.85).aspx) assembly. Sorry, I have no vista installation on which to check, but I hope these links are useful!

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
import time, datetime
fstat = os.stat(FILENAME)
st_mtime = fstat.st_mtime # Date modified
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i = time.localtime(st_mtime)
print datetime.datetime(a,b,c,d,e,f,g)
```

Answer (score 1):

(You might notice a longer version of the following response given on [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512435/how-do-you-retrieve-the-tags-of-a-file-in-a-list-with-python-windows-vista/5846091) of your threads.)

1. Download and install the [pywin32 extension](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/).
2. Grab [the code](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/get-document-summary-info.html) Tim Golden wrote for this very task.
3. Save Tim's code as a module on your own computer.
4. Call the `property_sets` method of your new module (supplying the necessary filepath). The method returns a generator, which is iterable.  See the following example code and output.