# How to access file metadata with Python?

Tags: python, windows, metadata

I'm trying to write a program in python that retrieves and updates file metadata on windows. I've tried searching on Google regarding what modules to use but I haven't found anything very concrete or useful.

Some people suggested the [stat module](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/module-stat.html) which can give you info such as file access and last modification. But I'm looking to retrieve other types of metadata available on Windows. For example tags, author, rating, artists etc.

How can I retrieve this information for a file using Python?

Thanks

Comment: Near Duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512435/how-do-you-retrieve-the-tags-of-a-file-in-a-list-with-python-windows-vista/

Answer (score 2):

Essentially as I said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512435/how-do-you-retrieve-the-tags-of-a-file-in-a-list-with-python-windows-vista) less than an hour ago,

> Apparently, you need to use the
>   Windows Search API looking for
>   System.Keywords -- you can access the
>   API directly via ctypes, or indirectly
>   (needing win32 extensions) through the
>   API's COM Interop assembly. Sorry, I
>   have no vista installation on which to
>   check, but I hope these links are
>   useful!

Links don't preserve across copy and paste, please just visit the other SO questions for them;-).