# Embedding Metadata in a File(Visual C++)

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, text-editor

I have written a simple MFC text editor in Visual C++ and I was wondering how I might go about embedding metadata into a file. For eg. author, date of creation, etc. Don't need you to tell me step by step, just need you to guide me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556382/does-windows-support-metadata-for-every-file

Comment: You want to write a shell extension so that you can, for example, add a column in Explorer and sort by metadata extracted from your special file type?

Comment: no...i simply want to embed in a document, the author and date of creation.