# How to get a File description(Product name, Original filname, etc.) using golang in windows?

Tags: go

Fileinfo in golang gives Name, time modified, size, etc. I need to get particular File's description(eg: Product name, Original filname, etc.) using golang in windows.

Comment: What kinds of files are these? Is that info contained in the file format, or somehow stored in some windows specific metadata area?

Comment: If its something like ntfs alternate data streams, it could take some syscall voodoo, and I can't seem to find any existing usages in go.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1556384/121660

Comment: @captncraig: I think what OP is actually looking for is how to call the C function [`GetFileVersionInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647003(v=vs.85).aspx) from Go.

Comment: @captncraig: It's file meta data. These are executable files.

Comment: @TimCooper: Yes, exactly.

Comment: @NandhakumarBalasubramaniam: Are you looking for a solution with or without cgo?

Comment: @TimCooper: A solution with cgo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [w32 library](https://github.com/gonutz/w32) for Win32 API calls from Go. No CGo needed.

Here is an example of how you can retrieve all file information through GetFileVersionInfo and VerQueryValue:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gonutz/w32/v2"
)

func main() {
    const path = `C:\some file`

    size := w32.GetFileVersionInfoSize(path)
    if size <= 0 {
        panic("GetFileVersionInfoSize failed")
    }

    info := make([]byte, size)
    ok := w32.GetFileVersionInfo(path, info)
    if !ok {
        panic("GetFileVersionInfo failed")
    }

    fixed, ok := w32.VerQueryValueRoot(info)
    if !ok {
        panic("VerQueryValueRoot failed")
    }
    version := fixed.FileVersion()
    fmt.Printf(
        "file version: %d.%d.%d.%d\n",
        version&0xFFFF000000000000>>48,
        version&0x0000FFFF00000000>>32,
        version&0x00000000FFFF0000>>16,
        version&0x000000000000FFFF>>0,
    )

    translations, ok := w32.VerQueryValueTranslations(info)
    if !ok {
        panic("VerQueryValueTranslations failed")
    }
    if len(translations) == 0 {
        panic("no translation found")
    }
    fmt.Println("translations:", translations)

    t := translations[0]
    // w32.CompanyName simply translates to "CompanyName"
    company, ok := w32.VerQueryValueString(info, t, w32.CompanyName)
    if !ok {
        panic("cannot get company name")
    }
    fmt.Println("company:", company)
}
```