# Get custom property of a file in python

Tags: python, linux, windows

I know that it's easy to get a standard property from a file, (like modification time, or owner, etc.) using python (just use os.stat(filename) ).

But,
If I have a file which has a custom property e.g Version_number , how can I get this one?
I try to list all the values out of os.stat(filename) but couldn't find Version_number there.
Any help will appreciated. 
Thanks. (BTW i'm using windows 7)

Comment: How do you know that the file has a custom property `Version_number`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5846021/2387370) answer. It suggests using [Python win32 extensions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/), however this project seems to be for Python 2.7 and earlier so it won't work for Python 3.x if you are using that.

Alternatively try advice in [this](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/444174-accessing-windows-file-metadata#post1694511) answer - using DSOFILE.DLL (although this advice might be obsolete for windows 7). However what I understood from it, the method to get this metadata varies with file type, so more details might be helpful.