# extract keywords metadata from file python

Tags: python, metadata, keyword

i'm tried yesterday all day to extract this information and i didn't reach information about that.

[image: keywods]

i tried with the next libraries:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hachoir-metadata/1.3.3
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ExifRead

the tags data is my headache =) 
this image for example: http://cdn.eso.org/images/screen/eso1238a.jpg

Comment: Which information?  What specifically did you try and in what way did it fail? (Without these details your question is unanswerable.  That is why you are seeing close votes.)

Comment: To help you we need a meaningful input file example, your existing code and the corresponding output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you retrieve the tags of a file in a list with Python (Windows Vista)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512435/how-do-you-retrieve-the-tags-of-a-file-in-a-list-with-python-windows-vista)

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5846021/2351523).