# Python get data from custom tab in file's properties

Tags: python, powershell, metadata

I'm strungling with what's seems to be custom metadata tab.
I spend 16 hour trying to write a snippet to read data from this tab 'Phenom-World':

[image: Data to read]

I tried different approach without any success :

1. Exif
2. [Win32com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584038/get-the-list-of-metadata-associated-to-a-file-using-python-in-ubuntu/5846021#5846021)
3. os.stat

My attempts are returning information relative to File>Properties>Details (size, résolution, date, etc) but nothing from the tab named 'Phenom-World'.

Any help please ? I'm kind of despair now.
Thanks for your help !

[Here's the file, it's a .jpeg](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j_ksp0Vy9rKCdnxUIOYpFwfVrJM7sta0/view?usp=sharing)

I'm using python 3.8, windows 10

---

EDIT #1

It seems that the phenom-world tab can only be seen by computers where a software from this same brand is installed.

I send the file 6.jpeg to another computer able to read it, it return exactly the same datas, so those metadata are embeded in the file even through if they are 'hidden' for computer without the phenom software.

Comment: Looking at the file properties I don't see Phenom-World tab

Comment: Indeed, i checked on another computer and i do not see "phenom-world" tab either.